# Can Codeigniter write_file write a UTF-8 file?

Tags: codeigniter, utf-8

In CodeIgniter, I'm writing an XML file using write_file function.

```
write_file('data.xml', $str_xml);
```

But the encoding of the file is always ANSI. How can I have this 
file be encoded to UTF-8 automatically?

Comment: How are you determining the file's encoding?

Comment: How to create the $str_xml? There set the character encoding!  
The write_file() function only write the data into a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, thanks for any suggestion. I've just figured it out myself. What I need is the PHP function called "utf8_encode()". Like this...

```
write_file('data.xml', utf8_encode($str_xml));
```

Now the file is saved to UTF-8 automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the function in question, but I assume it will write out the bytes it receives. Except for the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark), there is no defined indicator how a file is encoded: It will depend on *what you open the file as*.

UTF-8 encoding will look like Ansi for the first 127 characters of the ASCII table, and switch to multi-byte characters when encountering characters outside that. It is therefore perfectly possible that a UTF-8 encoded file looks totally identical to an ANSI one if it doesn't contain any special characters.

I can be wrong, but my suspicion is the file is UTF-8 but whatever you're using to test the encoding with is giving you the wrong result. Could that be?